# Airflow init in Docker creates empty directories

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

One of the projects I am working on is using airflow. So, I used [airflow's](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) documentation to install airflow with docker compose.

I wanted the `dags` `plugin` and `logs` directories to not be in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yaml`, so I put them inside another directory called `airflow` and referenced the directory inside the `docker-compose.yaml`, like so:

```
  volumes:
    - ./airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
```

Whenever I run the docker-compose, airflow-init service creates the three directories again in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yaml` (I realized they appear when it starts running). It is not a big problem, since I can just ignore them. They are empty and airflow correctly uses the directories inside the `airflow` directory. But I wanted to know if there was a way to stop these directories from being created.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the volumes for all services?

Comment: Oh, you are right. airflow-init service had a volumes field that I completely missed. I changed it to `./airflow/` and the directories stopped showing up.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because your version also addresses the part changing the permissions after creating the directories. I think you should post the answer in benefit of those who'll come after you

Comment: Looking at the script, they only mounted created that volume to create and modify permissions of the required folders, so just changing the source of that volume is enough

Comment: I would have accepted the answer as soon as SO allowed me. You have a point, changing the `volumes` section seems to prevent me from typing it four times all over the place again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @EDG956 for the help.

There is a `volumes` field inside the `airflow-init` service that I completely missed. You can change the volume mount from

```
volumes:
      - .:/sources
```

to:

```
volumes:
      - ./airflow/:/sources
```

Or change the part of the `command` field that creates the directories in the `/sources` volume, like so:

```
        mkdir -p /sources/airflow/logs /sources/airflow/dags /sources/airflow/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/airflow/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
```

Although as @EDG956 pointed out, the first solution seems to be more efficient.